# G is an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, abelian-groups

Let $(G, .)$ a group. Suppose $G = \{1, x, y, z\}$ is of order 4. Show that $G$ is abelian.

Am I right to say that, as $G$ is of order $4$, then by Lagrange's Theorem, there exists $g \in G$ such that $
\langle g\rangle = G$. From there it becomes clear that $G$ is abelian. Am I on the right track?

**EDIT:** There were two exercises before asking if $xy = x$ then $y = 1$ and if $xy \not = 1$ then $yx \not = 1$. Do I have to use those?

Comment: No, it's not necessarily the case that $G$ is cyclic.  All you know for sure is that the order of every element of $G$ *divides* $4$.  You can get where you need to be by considering the possible results of $x \cdot y$ and the possible results of $y \cdot x$.  You'll see they have to end up in the same place, and that reasoning will carry over to the other possible products.  Yes, the exercises will come in handy to make these calculations quicker.

Comment: By Lagrange, the order of any element divides the order of the group. You seem to be trying to use a converse (that is $k$ divides the order of $G$, then there is an element of order $k$?) but that is false.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The latter are relation symbols, so they have equal spacing on both sides. The former are delimiters, so they have proper spacing to use for groupings.

Comment: Hint: What can $xy$ be equal to? It cannot be $x$ or $y$, so it is either $1$ or $z$. Either way, what is $yx$? Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Can you build a full answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g\in G$ has order $4$, then $G=\langle g\rangle$;
otherwise, since the order of $g$ divides $4$, we get $g^2=1$, for every $g\in G$.

Thus $$xy=x1y=x((xy)(xy))y=(xx)(yx)(yy)=1(yx)1=yx.$$

Comment: "we get $g^2=1$, for every $x\in G$". I think there is an error there.

Comment: @Alex If there is no element of order $4$, then all elements must have order $1$ or $2$; either way, $x^2=1$.

Comment: Ah, ok, I changed from $g$ to $x$, you're right!